# Check if there is more than x bytes on ANY drive c#

Tags: c#, foreach, driveinfo

I'm kinda new to this so I'll just get to it. 
I'm trying to figure out how to check if ANY drive has 30 GB disk space,
So far I can't seem to get it to do more than just checking the C: drive.

Probably has to do with the fact that CopyAvailableCheck() only checks the first value it gets, which is from the C: drive, but I have no clue how to fix that.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Here is my code:

```
public class DriveCheck
{
   private void CopyAvailableCheck()
   {
        if (FreeDriveSpace() == 1)
        {
          // do something
        }     
        else if (FreeDriveSpace() == 0)
        {
            // Something Else

        }
        else if (FreeDriveSpace() == -1)
        {
            // Something else

        }
   }  

   public static int FreeDriveSpace()
   {
        DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
        foreach (DriveInfo d in allDrives)
        {
            if (d.IsReady == true)
            {
                // If total free space is more than 30 GB (default)
                if (d.TotalFreeSpace >= 32212254720) // default: 32212254720
                {
                    return 1; // If everything is OK it returns 1
                }
                else
                {
                    return 0; // Not enough space returns 0
                }
            }

        }
        return -1; // Other error returns -1
    }
}
```

Comment: You seem to have C or C++ experience :)

Comment: Don't you think it would make sense to return the drive-name instead of "0" or "1" ?

Comment: You can replace this `d.IsReady == true` with just `d.IsReady`

Comment: But your code will stop after the C: drive if it has enough space, that seems correct?  In other words, what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't check multiple drives because you are returning from the method inside the loop that checks the disk.

You need to change the result of the method to be an object that can be consume by the caller that shows the answer for each drive.

Try something like this...

```
private void CopyAvailableCheck()
{
    var listOfDisks = FreeDriveSpace();

    foreach( var disk in listOfDisks )
    {
        if ( disk.Status == 1)
        {
         // do something
        }
        else if ( disk.Status = 0 )
        {
          //do something else
        }
    }
}

public static List<Disk> FreeDriveSpace()
{
    DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
    var listOfDisks = new List<Disk>();

    foreach (DriveInfo d in allDrives)
    {
        var currentDisk = new Disk( d.Name );   
        if (d.IsReady == true)
        {
            // If total free space is more than 30 GB (default)
            if (d.TotalFreeSpace >= 32212254720) // default: 32212254720
            {
                currentDisk.Status = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                currentDisk.Status = 0; // Not enough space
            }
        }
        listOfDisks.Add( currentDisk );
    }

    return listOfDisks;  
}


public class Disk
{
    public Disk( string name )
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public int Status
    {
        get; set;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

This wasn't written in VS, it might not be perfect.

Comment: hmh, now I'm getting "'System.IO.DriveInfo' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?" on d.Status = 1; and d.Status = 0;

Answer (score 4):

If you `return` within your loop, you will never get to the next item.

In C#, with Linq, you can get the collection of drives with a line like this:

```
var drivesWithSpace = DriveInfo.GetDrives().Where (di => di.IsReady && di.TotalFreeSpace > 32212254720)
```

You can then iterate through the list:

```
foreach (DriveInfo drive in drivesWithSpace)
{
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (DriveInfo d in allDrives)
        {
            if (d.IsReady == true)
            {
                // If total free space is more than 30 GB (default)
                if (d.TotalFreeSpace >= 32212254720) // default: 32212254720
                {
                    return 1; // If everything is OK it returns 1
                }
                else
                {
                    return 0; // Not enough space returns 0
                }
            }

        }
```

So this foreach will at most iterate over one drive whether the drive has space or not. It doesn't matter how many times you call it. The result will *always* be the same (as long as no serious read/write operations have been done).

Maybe you want to store the drive name somewhere and return the first drive with available size?

Answer (score 0):

The loop in your `FreeDriveSpace` method runs only once because it `return`s either `0` or `1` in its first pass.

What you want is for it to return `1` if it finds any drive with more than 30 GB free space, otherwise return `0`:

```
   public static int FreeDriveSpace()
   {
        DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
        foreach (DriveInfo d in allDrives)
        {
            if (d.IsReady == true && d.TotalFreeSpace >= 32212254720)
            {
                return 1; // the control only reaches this return statement if a drive with more than 30GB free space is found
            }

        }
        // if the control reaches here, it means the if test failed for all drives. so return 0.
        return 0; 
    }
```

By the way I recommend using `enum`s instead of magic numbers for errors.